# How interface calls ToString method of object class

Tags: c#

As per my understanding `interface` is not derived from `Object` as other classes, so how interface is allowed to call `ToString()` method of an `Object` class.

```
interface I1
{
}

class D
{
    I1 i;
    public D()
    {
        string s = i.ToString(); // why compiler doesn't complain here?
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in comment, *Everything derived from Object*, here is some contradictory article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/

Comment: Why should it ? Pretty much *Everything* in C# is derived from `object`

Comment: @Fabjan if you read blog by Eric Lippert, he mentioned interfaces are not Object

Comment: @lmad it doesn't matter because interface has to be implemented by some object that's why compiler assumes that there is object there (which means that it inherits from `System.Object` for sure)

Comment: @Fabjan yes, that means it is at least clear that my understanding about interface not being Object was clear (which probably earned me down-vote). Second, yes, it will eventually be implemented but how it is known to compiler?

Comment: @lmad I don't think that compiler *knows* that, it just *presumes* that and acts based on this assumption. Probably it was designed this way to eliminate the need of redundant check that whatever type implements the interface also implements the `System.Object`

Comment: @Fabjan Yes, probably...

Comment: From the article you quote, saying that interfaces don't derive from object: "*Interface types, not being classes, are not derived from object. They are all convertible to object, to be sure, because we know that at runtime the instance will be a concrete type*". So there exists a conversion from any interface type to object, which has the same effect. Although as @Progman's answer explains, the spec makes it clear that a base type of an interface *is* object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the methods from `Object` because the [Standard ECMA-334 
C# Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) says so:

> **14. Expressions**
>
> **14.3 Member lookup**
>
> **14.3.1 Base types**
>
> For purposes of member lookup, a type T is considered to have the following base types:
>
> [...]
>
> - If `T` is an *interface-type*, the base types of `T` are the base interfaces of `T` and the class type `object`.

That's why you can call `ToString()` on a variable that use an interface as the type, even though there is no `ToString()` method defined in that interface.

Answer (score 2):

[Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)

Excerpt:

> Besides any types that they may inherit from through single inheritance, all types in the .NET type system **implicitly inherit from Object or a type derived from it**. The common functionality of Object is available to any type.

`i` has to be a instantiated type, so it's probably implicitly (un)boxed to object and thus `.ToString()` works.

Comment: That excerpt is contradict with Eric Lippert https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/

but yes as he used work `convertible` and that make me more confused.